# Submit server IP from wifi router to Android

Tags: java, android, networking, lan

I'm currently writing an app that's to connect to a server over a wireless lan.

So far, I've got the IP address hardcoded into the app (which works perfectly), however, the next logical step is to be able to send the app the server IP address.

From what I understand, the router needs to broadcast the IP address over 255.255.255.255 - apart from that, I have no idea what to do.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated

---

edit

ok, so I know to get this working, all phones have to be on the same network as the server, which is fine.

What I need to do is get the phone to broadcast on the network whilst my server listens. From there, the server sends the app its IP address, then the rest of the code can continue.

Does anyone have a tutorial or anything I can follow to get both sides working?

Comment: Just to make sure we know exactly what you intend to do: You want the app to work in *one specific* wireless lan? And you want the router of that specific network to tell your app automatically which server she should use?

Comment: yeah - I'll set up a lan when I want the system to work (call it mylan), the users connect to mylan and will then be able to connect to the server

Comment: I'm not sure how you would go about accessing wifi stuff, because Android handles all the wifi handshakes and the DHCP stuff itself. The question is: Is it possible to plug in your own event handler there in order to catch the DHCP response or whether you need to do a similar request yourself after Android established a connection.

Comment: This is a networking problem, not a programming one. You may want buy a domain for your server, or use dyndns. Then hardcode the URL.

Comment: @MisterSmith - I'm not going through DNS

Comment: @Krath You should. It decouples a site identification from its phisical IP address. Otherwise you can post a file (in some file hosting service) containing the IP so that you can change it later. Then in your app, download that file and get the IP.

Comment: @MisterSmith yeah, but the system may not have access to an internet connection, which is why I'm using a lan.

Comment: @Krath Then include an EditText in you app so that the user is able to configure the IP.

Comment: So your server is only accessible on the intranet, not the internet, is that correct? That excludes domains. But shouldn't your *server* be broadcasting its address to the lan instead of the *router*?

Comment: @Marcelo bingo! That's what I meant to say, sorry >.<

Answer (score 0):

one simple solution for you not to hardcode the server's IP or name (let us say it changes over time), would be for you to implement a name server on your network and have the android device call a local URL.

you could then post the current server's IP or name in the header of a web page on your local network.  this response would then be used by android app.